I get MISSING_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER from sendVerificationCode api firebase
I tried my code in laravel php  to send otp from firebase by phone number , but I get always MISSING_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER  in the response , I already activated the phone authentication service in my firebase app ,
    $phone = $request->get('phone');
        $apiKey = 'my key'; 


        try {
            $client = new Client();
            $response =$client>post('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendVerificationCode?key=' . $apiKey, [
                'json' => [
                    'phoneNumber' => "+".$phone           
                ]
            ]);

            $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

the response is
"error": "Client error: POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendVerificationCode?key=my key resulted in a 400 Bad Request response:\n{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "MISSING_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": " (truncated...)\n"
I want to send the code and verify the code in another api

The error message seems very clear. It wants a client identifier. You are only sending a phone number. What's the problem?

The API you're calling has documentation.  I suggest reviewing that to understand what it requires and how it works.

Thank you @miken32 , my problem is I am using it as backend just, how can I generate the reCAPTCHA token from backend just, and the reCAPTCHA token is enough with the phone number to send the otp ?

Thank you @DougStevenson , the response still get the same, my problem is I am using it as backend just, how can I generate the reCAPTCHA token from backend just, and the reCAPTCHA token is enough with the phone number to send the otp ?
